# Rendering issue with IE and Firefox using Highchart heatmaps

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I have rendering problem of datalabels in the highcharts heatmaps for IE and firefox, can anyone help me how to fix the rendering problem

[image]

Comment: You really should show us some code

Comment: Please, recreate issue on jsfiddle. It looks like you have some options which cause that behaviour (for example `dataLabels.y` or `dataLabels.useHTML`?).

Comment: I fixed it. Actually padding and position of y axis of dataLabels had caused the problem